# How can I Select the MAX of a Column using Zend_Db_Table?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

What is the easiest, simplest way to select the max of a column from a table using Zend_Db_Table?  Basically, I just want to run this query in Zend:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS maxID FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use Zend_Db_Expr to use mysql functions:

```
return $this->fetchAll(
            $this->select()
                ->from($this, array(new Zend_Db_Expr('max(id) as maxId')))
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run direct sql, using `$db->query();` yours would simply be:

```
$db->query("SELECT MAX(id) AS maxID FROM myTable");
```

but if you want the object notation, then you'd do something like this:

```
$db->select()->from("myTable", array(new Zend_Db_Expr("MAX(id) AS maxID")));
```

Answer (score 2):

For those looking to just select the max id from their id column in Zend Framework 2 (maybe 3 as well), but getting this error...

> While processing primary key data, a known key id was not found in the data array

...note that you'll need to alias `MAX(id)` as `id`.

Example inside a table extended from the `TableGateway` class:

```
$select = $this->sql->select();
$select->columns(['id' => new Expression('MAX(id)')]);
$maxId = $this->selectWith($select)->current()->id;
return (int) $maxId;
```

Comment: I added the version as a tag to the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is like this :

```
$select=new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$select->from(array($table),array('max($column)'));
$select->where('condition');
$answer=$db->fetchOne($select);
```

If You do it like this , you can edit it later easier!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$select = new Select();
$select->from('tablename');
$select->where(array('post_id', 1));
$select->columns(array('id' => new Expression('MAX(id)')));
$results = $this->getTableGateway()->selectWith($select);
```

Comment: What about a little explanation?